# Keyboard not working during boot after using Ubuntu and then restarting. Have to restart twice for it to work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed, and Windows 10 is also installed on another SSD, so I can dual boot.

Whenever I use Ubuntu, and then restart the computer, the keyboard doesn't work before the OS is loaded. That means I can't access the BIOS, nor I can do anything during the Grub screen (like choose Windows, for example), which means that if I wait, Ubuntu is loaded after the timeut since it's the default OS

So if I want to use Windows, I have to manually restart my PC before Ubuntu is loaded. On this restart, the keyboard works again. I've noticed that if I use Windows, and then restart, this problem doesn't happen, it only happens if the last OS I used was Ubuntu.

I've tested with two keyboards on different USB ports. I've also checked USB Legacy Support is on. And also this problem started months ago, while I had installed Ubuntu 19.04, which I upgraded recently to 20.04, but that didn't solve the issue.

Specs:

- Gigabyte Aorus Z390 (Bios 10b)
- Intel i9 9900K
- 32 GB of DDR4 RAM
- Ubuntu and Windows are installed in different SSDs
- Got a wired Razer keyboard (plugged to rear USB port) and a Wireless Logitech keyboard (adapter is plugged to front USB port)

Comment: When was the last time that bios was updated?  Do not think that this is a Ubuntu or Windows caused problem, even if it sounds like Ubuntu has something to do with it.  Might help to put computer specs in question to see if anyone else has had this problem.  Might be known bug.

Comment: I updated my BIOS around 7 or 8 months ago. I'm sure that didn't cause the issue, because it's more recent (like 2 months ago or so)

Comment: No solution but seems like known problem.  One link found on google.  https://forum.gigabyte.us/thread/982/usb-mouse-work-bios-more

Comment: Have read of from problems with computers that was caused by something outside of computer.  Move the computer and problem goes away, move back and problem comes back.  Usually a weak/wonky power connection somewhere.